# why my script in /etc/init.d with K symbolic link in rc0.d and rc6.d and S symbolic link in rc5.d is not working on shutdown?

Tags: bash, runlevel

I'm writing a script which I want to run before every shutdown of my ubuntu system. I have placed my script named myscript inside /etc/init.d folder and then created symbolic links in rc0.d and rc6.d as K01myscript and S01myscript in rc5.d. But the problem is that the script is not running at all.
I tried running it manually i.e. sudo /etc/init.d/myscript and it's working fine.

My script -

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
LOGPATH=/home/user/Documents
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/decomission
now=$(date +'%T')

start() {
    touch $lockfile
    echo "[$now] System startup" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

stop() {
    echo "[$now] System shutdown" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
    rm -f $lockfile
}

status() {
    echo "[$now] Hi, you're checking status" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: there is a very detailed explanation of what you are trying to do on the [Unix&Linux sister site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown).  I would check there first.  Also make sure the script is executable: `sudo chmod +x path/to/yourscript.sh`

Comment: @Nmath thanks for your response. I tried that too but no luck. I'm adding my script. Please have a look

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? Actual releases make use of `systemd` and SysV init scripts should no longer be used. Take a look at `systemd` and how to start/stop services.

Comment: @Thomas I'm using Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Just tested with SysV style and did work. But set `LOGPATH=/var/log` and without lockfile. You could add `exec &> /var/log/myscript.debug` right after `#!/bin/sh` to debug the script.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your suggestion about the systemd way, it worked but I will try SysV way also and will let you know the result.